# Suppress ANT build log in Jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, ant, build.xml

How to suppress ANT build log getting displayed on the jenkins console?

For windows batch command I tried echo off and it worked. But ANT build log is not suppressed. Is there any way to customize the Jenkins Console log?

Comment: Are you calling the ANT command from an "Execute Windows Batch command" build step or using an "Invoke Ant" step?

Comment: I am using 'Invoke ANT' step.

Comment: This build step type has many limits. Would you consider changing?

Comment: Yeah definitely , if there is any possible workaround for suppressing console log.

Answer (score 1):

Look into setting either `-quiet` `-silent` rather than suppress the output entirely.

That or change your ant script to be less chatty.  If you start calling ant from commandline to redirect the output you're going to make any build failures less transparent or possibly mess up the error handling and not catch the error.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Jenkins launches Execute Shell script with `set -x`. This causes all commands to be echoed

You can type `set +x` before any command to temporary override that behavior. You can override this behaviour for the whole script by putting the following at the top of the build step:

```
#!/bin/bash +x
```

Comment: This is at best masking the problem.  It's a bad plan - the other answer is the a much better one.